# Spring + Velocity Email template not rendering Html on mail body

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

I am trying create Email Template in spring + velocity .I am getting Email from this and content from template as well but the html in my template of velocity is not rendered on mail body.
Here is my java function of sending email template

```
public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body)
{
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

    message.setFrom(this.userName);
    message.setTo(to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(body);


    Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate("Templates/EmailTemplate.vm");
    VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
    velocityContext.put("firstName", "Yashwant");
    velocityContext.put("lastName", "Chavan");
    velocityContext.put("location", "Pune");

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    template.merge(velocityContext, stringWriter);
    message.setText(stringWriter.toString());

    mailSender.send(message);
}
```

and my velocity Template is

```
<html>
 <body>
<b>Dear ${firstName} ${lastName}</b>

 Sending Email Using Spring Smtp Email + Velocity Template from ${location}     location.

Thanks
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `SimpleMailMessage` only sends plain-text e-mails so you cannot use html with it.

Take a look at examples in Spring documentation that use `MimeMessageHelper`. `MimeMessageHelper` has method `setText` that has second boolean parameter with which you can specify if the text is html (e.g. passing in `true` means text is html). Take a look at the following example in the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html#mail-usage-mime

(There's also Velocity based example further down in the docs).